# Why does loopback give me an empty ctx.options for operation hooks?

Tags: node.js, express, loopback

this issue is also submitted to github: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/4024.

in our application we have defined an operation hook "before save".
With it we intend to do some validations about the requesting user.

In order to access the requesting user´s id, we are trying to get his accessToken from the optionsobject of the context parameter. This is done in accordance to the official loopback docs (
https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Using-current-context.html#access-the-context-from-operation-hooks)

The below code has been reduced to the minimum things for debugging:

```
Progress.observe('before save', function verifyAccessToken(ctx, next) {
        console.log('Executing before save');
        if (!ctx) {
            next(new Error('No ctx was passed to verifyMyUserExists'));
        }
        else if (!ctx.options) {
            console.log('Ctx is:');
            next(new Error('No options in ctx was passed to verifyMyUserExists'));
        }
        else if (!ctx.options.accessToken) {
            console.log('Options is:');
            console.log(ctx.options);
            next(new Error('No accessToken options in ctx was passed to verifyMyUserExists'));
        }
        else {
            next();
        }
    });
```

As of this week - without changing a thing in the code - this validation does not work any longer.
Based on this I got to know that the ctx.options is an empty object of {} (See full error log below).
Because of this we are not able to access the accessToken of course,

We did some troubleshooting and were not able to find the root cause, why the ctx.options is empty.

1. We are using the hook for standard operations on simple persisted
   models (NO custom methods. Just basic things.)
2. We ensured options are indeed injected (see code above and output below)
3. Take note, that we have embedded another model into the persisted model where the error occurs. But to our knowledge this should not be an issue, as it worked before.

**Expected result**

We would expect the operation hook´s parameter ctx to be populated with a full options object containing at least the accessToken of the requesting user.

Any thoughts on this? I am looking forward to your response and any ideas.

Best,
enosinger

**Additional information**

We are using Loopback 3.
We observe the error on our local machines and in Heroku running the app as a normal node app.

The full error log for the operation hook is:

```
Executing before save
Options is:
{}
Nicht verarbeiteter Fehler für Anforderung POST /api/progresses/?access_token=<XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX>: Error: No accessToken options in ctx was passed to verifyMyUserExists
    at verifyAccessToken (C:\Users\erosinger3\workspace_FitChallenger\Backend\common\models\progress.js:34:18)
    at notifySingleObserver (C:\Users\erosinger3\workspace_FitChallenger\Backend\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\observer.js:160:22)
    at C:\Users\erosinger3\workspace_FitChallenger\Backend\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:3096:16
    at replenish (C:\Users\erosinger3\workspace_FitChallenger\Backend\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:998:17)
    at C:\Users\erosinger3\workspace_FitChallenger\Backend\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:1002:9
    at eachLimit$1 (C:\Users\erosinger3\workspace_FitChallenger\Backend\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:3182:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\erosinger3\workspace_FitChallenger\Backend\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:1032:16)
    at doNotify (C:\Users\erosinger3\workspace_FitChallenger\Backend\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\observer.js:157:11)
    at doNotify (C:\Users\erosinger3\workspace_FitChallenger\Backend\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\observer.js:155:49)
    at doNotify (C:\Users\erosinger3\workspace_FitChallenger\Backend\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\observer.js:155:49)
    at doNotify (C:\Users\erosinger3\workspace_FitChallenger\Backend\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\observer.js:155:49)
    at Function.ObserverMixin._notifyBaseObservers (C:\Users\erosinger3\workspace_FitChallenger\Backend\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\observer.js:178:5)
    at Function.ObserverMixin.notifyObserversOf (C:\Users\erosinger3\workspace_FitChallenger\Backend\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\observer.js:153:8)
    at Function.ObserverMixin._notifyBaseObservers (C:\Users\erosinger3\workspace_FitChallenger\Backend\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\observer.js:176:15)
    at Function.ObserverMixin.notifyObserversOf (C:\Users\erosinger3\workspace_FitChallenger\Backend\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\observer.js:153:8)
    at Function.ObserverMixin._notifyBaseObservers (C:\Users\erosinger3\workspace_FitChallenger\Backend\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\observer.js:176:15)
```

Please excuse the German Error Messages. I do not know why the have been localized after I updated VS Code today ...

Comment: I can recommend to check https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-datasource-juggler/blob/master/lib/dao.js file.

Find Model.notifyObserversOf('before save') of your execution dao function and debug it. 

For me, the code looks great. May be one of the other observers deletes the options. If so, just temporary overwrite the source code, replace options property to setter and put breakpoint on it.